# Set up hook after query executes in activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to write a gem that will allow users to easily attach a hook or callback to an activerecord query, such as:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base 

  after_query do |result_set|
    # Place the body of the hook here
  end

end
```

Unfortunately I'm not finding a simple place to do this inside of `ActiveRecord`. If anyone has any pointers that would be great